# Reusable function/mixin for sass function

Tags: function, sass, mixins

I'm wondering if there's a simple way to re use a mixin simply by comma separating the passed information?

Example, if I wanted to output css based on how many things are passed through the mixin.

**MIXIN**

```
@mixin generate($number...){
   .item-#{$number} {@content}
}
```

**INCLUDE**

```
@include generate(1, 2){color:red;}
```

I'd like this to output:

```
.item-1 {color:red;}
.item-2 {color:red;}
```

**Example 2**

```
@include generate(1, 5, 6){color:red;}
```

Which would output:

```
.item-1 {color:red;}
.item-5 {color:red;}
.item-6 {color:red;}
```

This is a **VERY** simplified version of what I actually want, I don't care what the mixin looks like, or how it handles it, however I do want the include to look like this `@include generate(1,2,6,5){color:red;}`.

Thankyou!

Shannon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Basic usage

Use the [@each loop](http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#each-directive).

```
@mixin generate($numbers...){
  @each $number in $numbers {
   .item-#{$number} {@content;}
  }
}

@include generate(1, 2, 6);
```

Demo: http://sassbin.com/gist/5999585/

### Advanced usage

You can use the [@for loop](http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#id11) to have both item and its index. Also, you can use a list of lists to pass multiple values for each element:

```
=generate($items...)
  @for $i from 1 through length($items)
    $item: nth($items, $i)
    $offset: nth($item, 1)
    $color: nth($item, 2)

    .block-#{$i}
      margin-left: $offset
      background-color: $color

+generate(10 red, 20 green, 60 blue)
```

I've switched to the indented `.sass` syntax to get rid of curly braces and semicolons nuisance.

Demo: http://sassbin.com/gist/6007849/

### Precaution

I hope that your example is synthetic. If you use it like that in production, you're doing it wrong! Use [extends](http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#extend) instead:

```
%item { color: red};

.item-1, .item-2, .item-6 {
  @extend %item;
}
```

The resulting CSS will appear different (shorter but with same functionality):

```
.item-1, .item-2, .item-6 {
  color: red;
}
```

Demo: http://sassbin.com/gist/5999603/

Comment: As I mentioned in the example, it's a very simplified version of what I want :) It's actually to generate media queeries for advanced grids, but thankyou so much!

Comment: Hey @ShannonHochkins, for media queries see http://breakpoint-sass.com and http://github.com/lolmaus/breakpoint-slicer

Comment: Im creating my own plugin mate, but not only for break points, but to generate grid css, it's going to be quite the plugin :)

Comment: Have a look at [Singuarity](https://github.com/Team-Sass/Singularity) and how it integrates with Breakpoint and Breakpoint Slicer.

Comment: I have looked at it before, What I have done I believe is much easier to use, once I've finished it I'll link you for a review ;)

Comment: I'll be happy to have a look and give my opinion. I'll also try to show the Singularity way of doing what you did.